# .nfs file can't be removed - resource busy, but PID unknown

Tags: unix, nfs, fuser

There is a very large .nfs file on my system, and it's using a large amount of my disk quota. If I try to delete it, I get "rm: cannot remove '.nfs0000000001bd849100000001': Device or resource busy".

What's weird is that fuser -v .nfs0000000001bd849100000001 returns nothing and this system does not have lsof. So does anyone know how to remove this file?

Comment: @Avi - the answer in the link you provided is to use lsof which joesideburns has stated his system does not currently have.

Comment: yea I don't have permissions to install it either so I'm wondering if there's another way. But maybe there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old and I'm not sure if the circumstances I endured are similar or completely different. However, I did find the solution to my issue with the same symptom.

I was trying to clean a directory from build cruft via `rm -rf build/tmp/path` and a file deep in the tree named `.nfs000*` was throwing the "Device or resource is busy" error.

My problem was multi-faceted. The first element was the use of roaming home directories at the office. The second, was docker and the use of containers. Finally, vim and editing a file. While in the container, I was abruptly disconnected from my terminal which killed the shell and the vim program I had running, *but it did not kill the container*. However, because vim was dead no process did have that file open (but the container did). Finally, it wasn't called the usual `.something.swp` as vim temp file would because an attempt to delete it had taken place. That's when NFS stepped in to "save the day." Killing the containe solved the problem.

I don't know if this is what the OP had back then. I offer this only that, when someone else stumbles onto this, perhaps this will inspire you to think indirectly about the cause. [This link](https://www.unix.com/302524510-post7.html?s=81c5a7f932d128ec66dd7ed77ac87c44) actually provided me the inspiration for the problem. After `cat`ing the file, I found it was a VIM tmp file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too.

After looking at Andrew Falanga's answer above I did `top -u myusername` and found that there was a process going on which could have been doing something there. I killed that process with `kill -9 pid`  and then I could remove the offending files.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the folder with something else. See if the remove works post this action.
It works for me.